# How to add missing San Francisco font inside Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, fonts

I am running Xcode 8.3 , but I don't seem to have the San Francisco font present.

I already download it from https://developer.apple.com/fonts/ and install it. I can see it when I open Font Book on my mac.

Are there any additional steps to add the font inside Xcode ?

edit: I am designing my app in Interface Builder so I need to have the font in Xcode to see how it looks when I run it.

Comment: Please clarify your question. Are you trying to add the font to Xcode on your Mac or are you trying to add the font in an iOS app you are creating?

Comment: Well I want to add it to my app that I am making. But doesn't that mean I need to have it in Xcode ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you need to include it in your plist. There should be a plenty of threads with that. [This](http://codewithchris.com/common-mistakes-with-adding-custom-fonts-to-your-ios-app/) might help you

Comment: But San Francisco is not a custom font, it should be the default system font, right?

Comment: I believe that it depends on the version of your system. Since the older versions were using Helvetica.

Comment: I'm on the latest one, with the new Macbook Pro =/

Answer (score 5):

If you are targeting iOS 9 or later San Francisco is the default font. Usage in swift 3 `UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15)`

Comment: so how do you specify this default font to be regular or semibold on certain parts of the app? thank you

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue for an ios application built with React native. Using `react-native link` did not resolve my issue. The font assets where in the `Resources` folder and in `Build Phases > Copy Bundle Resources` yet the issue persisted. It was only resolved after I added the relative path to the actual fonts assets in my case `../lib/assets/fonts` to my plist under `Application fonts resource path`

[image: An image of the relecvant section of my Info.plist]

Don't forget about: `Build Phases > Copy Bundle Resources`